# Hide scrollbar in div with 100vh

Tags: html, css

I am having a great deal of trouble with a scrollbar in my [new portfolio](http://weshape.dk/newport/).

As you can see, the layout is divided into two columns, where my content is on the left side. I want to be able to scroll, but I need the scrollbar to be hidden. I have tried with the following code, but it didn't work. I don't know if it's a problem, that I use the 100vh setting?

**Example of what I tried**

```
.parent{
   height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.child{
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="container-fluid content">
        <div class="row row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-sm-6 static">
                <div class="text">
                    <div class="vertical">
                        <p>CONTENT</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 overflow-hidden">
                <div class="image personal">
                    <img src="IMAGE" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height` here -

```
.unslider {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

For hiding the inner scrollbar, you can add negative `margin` here -

```
.content .row .static {
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 -16px 0 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfect! Can you describe why this works, and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

```
.content .row .static{overflow:hidden;}
```

add the above code in the css

Comment: Doesn't work. If you do that, you aren't able to scroll.

Comment: so you don't want the scrollbar  for content part or for whole site??

Comment: I don't want the scrollbar anywhere, but I want to be able to scroll.

Comment: see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshMesser/VUSuZ/) example it may solve your issue

Comment: got it add this code  `.col-sm-6.static::-webkit-scrollbar{display : none;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
display: none; 
 }
```

But only Mozilla browzers support  Web-Kit, not IE